# Привязка TwoWay к List<int>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

```
List<int> Items { get; set; } = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

---

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=."}/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Вопрос: Как сделать так,чтобы значения можно было изменять в обе стороны,а не только при начальной привязке при загрузке формы.

p.s. не оборачивая int в класс.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, у меня такой же вопрос, но такой способ не помог.

Comment: Никак, нужно использовать обертку

Comment: Где-то был такой вопрос, сейчас поищу дубликат

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Напрямую привязаться не удастся, но это не сильно большая проблема.

Заводить обёртку вокруг `int` на уровне VM неправильно, поэтому применим конвертер.

```
class EditableValueTypeConverter<T> : IValueConverter where T : struct
{
    class ItemWrapper
    {
        public ItemWrapper(IList<T> container, int index) =>
            (this.container, this.index) = (container, index);
        IList<T> container;
        int index;
        public T Value
        {
            get => container[index];
            set => container[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object p, CultureInfo ci)
    {
        var list = (IList<T>)value;
        return Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                         .Select(idx => new ItemWrapper(list, idx))
                         .ToList();
        // или просто list.Select((t, idx) => new ItemWrapper(list, idx)).ToList()
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object p, CultureInfo ci) =>
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}

class IntListConverter : EditableValueTypeConverter<int> { }
```

Теперь наш XAML выглядит как-то так:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IntListConverter x:Key="IntListConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Converter={StaticResource IntListConverter}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}" Width="50"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Результат:

[image: ну как-то так вроде]

Comment: А почему `where T : struct`? Если у меня коллекция `string`? Ну и вместо `Enumerable.Range` можно сразу `list.Select((t, idx) => new ItemWrapper(list, idx))`

Comment: @АндрейNOP: `T: struct` потому, что для объектов проблема меньше: в них практически никогда не приходится заменять _весь_ объект, а только редактировать существующий. А значит, трюк не нужен. Исключение — строки, да, их заменяют целиком.

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Замена `list.Select` на `Enumerable.Range` — нанооптимизация: мы не дёргаем элементы списка, а лишь один раз опрашиваем длину. Впрочем, она и правда не стоит свеч плюс требует `IList<T>`. Спасибо, добавил вариант.

Comment: Ну дык речь именно про `string` - это хороший кандидат из типов-значений и, думаю, не так уж редко нужен (в сравнении с теми же int и др.). А замена `list.Select` на `Enumerable.Range` не для оптимизации использования ресурсов, а только лишь для сокращения кода :)